# HTML5 speech synthesis missing some text when reading

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to read(voice out) a web page with HTML5 speech synthesis. But it reads only few characters in the line. What would be the best option to read huge text. Is there any limitation with html5 speech synthesis?

My fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x831pe7j/1/)

```
// Create the utterance object
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
utterance.text = 'Just wanted to share my experience with the new dropbox option available.When I was trying to get some info before I opted for Dropbox, I could hardly find any motivation or any experiences shared, so I though of sharing my experience so that it might help others.To be on safe side, take the original and one copy of all the documents.';

// optional parameters
utterance.lang = 'en-GB'; // language, default is 'en-US'
utterance.volume = 0.5;   // volume, from 0 to 1, default is 1
utterance.rate = 0.9;     // speaking rate, default is 1 

// speak it!
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Comment: _"But it reads only few characters in the line."_ Cannot reproduce

Comment: I mean it is not reading whole text block.

Comment: At which browsers did you try JavaScript at Question? The entire text is rendered at speakers at chromium 59 and firefox 54 here

Comment: Tried in chrome. Anyone else cab reproduce?

Comment: Which version of chrome? Have you filed a bug? Which specific words are not rendered at audio output at speakers?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using Chrome 104 and Firefox 103 on Windows 10 with RAM at 53% of 16 GB in a HP Notebook 15-db0800nd with AMD Ryzen 3 2200U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2.50 GHz:

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const saying = new Set()
function say(s, rate=1.0, pitch=1.0, lang="en-US", volume=1.0){
    // rate: (0.1,10), pitch: (0,2), lang: BCP 47 language tag
    // So 0.1 < rate < 10, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)
    const u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(s)
    u.lang = lang
    u.pitch = pitch
    u.rate = rate
    u.volume = volume
    saying.add(u)
    u.onend = e => {
        saying.delete(e.utterance)
        if(saying.size < 1) [...document.getElementsByClassName("say")].forEach(e => e.disabled = false)
    }
    speechSynthesis.speak(u)
}
async function say_all_via_sleepy_jack(s){
    say('a', 9, 1, "en-US", 0)  // Wake sleeping audio jack.
    await sleep(1500).then(()=>say(s))
}
//let bad = setInterval(()=> say("Hello good morning"), 15000) // 13000 intermittendly.
let good = setInterval(()=> say_all_via_sleepy_jack("Hello good morning"), 15000)
```

Alternatively, keep this playing to avoid the speech delay:

```html
<audio autoplay loop id="woke">
    <source src="silent.ogx" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
    addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>window.woke.play())
</script>
```

In both cases you need to click on the page first to enable audio.